# R plotting table of incomplete dates

Tags: r, date, plot

Novice R question: given a number of observations over a range of dates, e.g.,

```
obs <- as.Date(c("2001-08-02","2001-08-02", "2001-08-02","2001-08-03", 
                "2001-08-04", "2001-08-04", "2001-08-07", "2001-08-07"))
```

I can plot the frequencies of observations over time with

```
plot(table(obs))
```

[image]

However, how can I generate a table plot from `obs` that includes all intermediate missing dates (i.e., "2001-08-05", "2001-08-06") showing zero frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
obs <- c(obs, seq(min(obs), max(obs), 1))
plot(table(obs) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the `hist` function instead, it covers cases like these.

```
hist(obs, breaks='day', format = "%d %b", freq=TRUE)
```